# Can I have application-specific passwords without 2-step verification for my Google account?

Tags: google-account, login, passwords, authentication, multi-factor-auth

Is it possible to use **application-specific passwords** on **Google** without going through all the hassles of the **2-step verification** authentication?

What if I don't want to tie myself to a phone number on a PSTN, but still want to have some application-specific passwords?

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: @Sathya, why not?

Comment: because it isn't supported. because app-specific passwords get flagged on your Google account only when you enable 2fA. Also, if you have a smartphone, you can install the Authenticator app, allowing for 2fA code generation, without the need for a data plan or for a constant phone number

Comment: I still haven't seen any explanation for this policy anywhere except "because that's how it works". What is the reason for this decision by Google?! Isn't it obvious that app-specific passwords are valuable on their own so you don't have give your password to every app?

Comment: It is indeed very stupid these two features are linked like that. My guess: Google wants to push you to use 2fa.

Comment: The specific answer is because phone numbers are data, and phone numbers prevent you from sharing an account. Better data and one-account-per-person are very attractive to Google. In China 2FA is mandatory on all websites (and phone numbers attach to national ID#).

Comment: @WilliamEntriken 'phone numbers prevent you from sharing an account' - this is incorrect. IT IS TO PREVENT SPAMMERS FROM HACKING ACCOUNTS.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to work around this by turning on 2-step verification, setting up app passwords, then turning 2-step verification back off. When you turn it off, it asks if you want to clear verification data. I said no; I don't know whether that matters. After turning it off, the app passwords link is still available, and my applications still login fine.

Comment: Sounds great!  I haven't tested this, but doing a +1 for you as you're a new user, and it sounds like this might indeed work.  If someone else could confirm or deny this claim, that'd be great!

Comment: I suspect Google may have disabled this workaround this week. I had been using it successfully until now. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Can confirm. I used to have an app-specific password like this from a few months ago. Today I tried to add a new app-specific password, and when I turned off 2-step verification (the last step in this process), the app passwords page says "The setting you are looking for is not available for your account." and the app-specific passwords do not work anymore.

Comment: As of 2019 this workaround seems to be working again. After creating the app-specific password and turning off 2-step verification, I still see "App Passwords" in the security page (so far, at least for an hour an counting).

Comment: 2019-09-10, not working again. After 2-step turned off, all app passwords are gone.

Comment: I can also confirm this does not work anymore as of 2020/05, what a shame.

Comment: I'm guessing with 2fa turned off then app specific passwords are no more secure and would grant access to top level Gmail.

Comment: Google no longer uses "google authenticator" or any other 2fa totp application unless you have a FIDO2 hardware key such as a yubikey.

Edit: They still do, but they hide it from the "2FA setup" interface. After enabling 2FA via Android Push notification, find it in "2-Step Verification" under "My Account"